# Poor performance selecting entities with many child collections using nHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm

I am having a performance issue on a system I'm working on when I try to load ~7700 records from the DB. NHB takes 10x longer to do its load, vs the same query using `SqlDataReader`. Obviously there is going to be some performance overhead using NHB, but 10x the time vs ADO.NET seems excessive. From what I can determine, NHB is the issue, specifically in how it handles the collections which hang off the entity.

We have this general issue across our system when we try to load large(ish) numbers of entities, when the entities themselves have a large number of collections hanging off them.

I'm hoping someone can lend some advice on how I can improve this issue.

The query is simple.

```
var employees = session.QueryOver<Employee>().List();
```

There are no Select n+1 / lazy fetching issues occurring either. The single DB statement issued is effectively `select * from employee`.

I wont post up the full fluent mapping for the entity unless someone asks, as its quite large, but its fairly standard. The entity in question consists of:

> 24 fields
>   3  1-1 Relationships
>   86 1-* Relationships

Extract:

```
HasMany(e => e.Roles)
.Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
.Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
.Fetch.Select()
.Inverse()
.LazyLoad()
.KeyColumns.Add("[EmployeeId]")
.Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();
```

Below are the average timings of 5 tests executed 1000 times. The timing starts / stops when I create/dispose of the NHB session, it does not include creation of the session factory.

```
00:00:00.7080910 - 7677 records loaded/entity instantiation/manual map using ADO.NET
00:00:01.6055084 - 7677 entities - session - Fields Only
00:00:01.7866198 - 7677 entities - session - Fields + 1-1 Relationships
00:00:11.3384154 - 7677 entities - session - Fields + 1-1 Relationships + 1-* Relationships
00:00:10.9083002 - 7677 entities - stateless session - Fields + 1-1 Relationships + 1-* Relationships
```

Just to be clear, this is not a DB/network/lazy fetching issue. IMO the issue seems to be in how NHB hydrates the entities.

**Edit**:Even though the fNHB mapping specifies caching, its disabled in the session factory. I explicitly removed them from the mapping files to verify, and the durations are unchanged.

I've also used ANTS to profile the code, and it seems the majority of time is spent in the `TwoPhaseLoad.InitializeEntity`. (Disregard the other 50% of the time, which is not shown below. Its nHibernates session factory, which is not the cause of the performance issue)

[image: ANTS Performance Profile Capture]

Environment:
nHibernate 3.3.1.4000, fnHibernate 1.3.0.733, MS SQL Server 2008, c# 4.0, Windows 7-64.

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with caching, what cache provider are you using? ADO.NET of course doesn't have the overhead of generating a cache key and checking the cache. And 86 1-* relationships is a very high number.

Comment: @JamieIde No, its not the cache. I should have said that. Even though our fNHB mappings include the cache entry, the session factory is created with the cache disabled (In general, we  found the 2nd level cache caused severe performance issues in our application)

Comment: @JamieIde Perhaps 86 1-* relationships are too much for NHB to handle, if this is the case, not a lot I can do. I'd like to see something concrete on this though, as there seems to be little information on how much is too much.

Comment: does it increase linear? So if you only add 1 `1-*` collection, what is the timing then?

Comment: btw 86 1-* collections also seem a bit overkill. Are they really needed on the root entity? Most of the time you are working one parts of the * part of the association referencing the user, no?

Comment: @Frio yea, the time is close to linear if test for 20,40,60,80 collections. They are needed also. Its one of the core entities in the application.

Comment: Yes, Employee is probably one of the core entities, but I think @Firo is asking whether all of the *collections* sprouting off of Employee are necessary.  It's best to only map the relationships that your application actually needs, and being careful to properly identify the root aggregates and model the relationships accordingly.  Just because a relationship *can* be modeled on the C# side of things doesn't mean it *should* be modeled.

Answer (score -1):

When writing the query, you have to include the .FetchMany(Func lambda) NHibernate extension to IQueryable.

For example if you query for Foos that are one to many with Bars:

```
class Foo 
{
    IList<Bar> Bars
}
```

instead of

`session.Query<Foo>().ToList();` (all)

you should write

`session.Query<Foo>().FetchMany( src => src.Bars ).ToList();`

which will tell nhibernate to fetch join instead of fetch select on each row.

Comment: please read the question. this is not the issue. i specifically say "There are no Select n+1 / lazy fetching issues occurring either"